# How do I switch from a quick app to an Android app?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Can I switch from a quick app to an Android app? How to operate it？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add an external schema to the activity of the target app to be redirected to. The sample code is as follows:

   ```
   <activity 

       android:label="@7F070043" 

       android:name="com.huawei.phoneservice.HelpCenterActivity" 

       android:exported="true" 

       android:excludeFromRecents="true" 

        android:launchMode="2" 

       android:configChanges="0x40002D84"> 

            <intent-filter> 

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action> 

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"> </category> 

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category> 

                   <data android:scheme="hwphoneservice" android:host="externalapp"></data> 

           </intent-filter> 

   </activity>
   ```
2. In the quick application, invoke the system.router.push interface to invoke the redirection function. That is, the router.push interface transfers the schema configured in the preceding step.

   ```
   router.push({uri:"hwphoneservice://externalapp/service"})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, switching from a QuickApp project to an Android project is not possible at the moment. I am not sure if such a feature is planned to be released in the near future but it should definitely be feasible.